# How do I load a sprite from .sks file to display in my ARSKView?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an ARKit app that uses SpriteKit to display SKNodes that correspond to ARAnchors in the AR session. I am using the `ARSKViewDelegate` method

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?
```

to display the nodes. This works for nodes I create and return in that method, but I have some more complicated nodes that I would like to design in an `.sks` file and then display for some anchors. When I return a node instantiated from an `.sks` file in that method the app crashes with an error saying the node is already in the scene (if the node is in the `.sks` file for the current scene), or already has a parent (if it is in an `.sks` file for a different scene).

How can I display sprites in ARKit that are drawn in an .sks file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "mySpriteKitScene") {
            
        guard let clone = scene.childNode(withName: "myRedSprite")?
                               .copy() as? SKSpriteNode
        else { return }

        clone.name = "mySecondRedSprite"
        clone.position.x += 250
        clone.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        scene.addChild(clone)

        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```